# How can I get the id (or some unique properties) of the USB devices connected to my Android device, programmatically?

Tags: android, usb

How can I get the id (or some unique properties) of the USB devices connected to my Android device?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone new to `UsbDevice`, it may be worth noting the use of `UsbManager`

```
UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
```

Read more at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html

Comment: It is not compatible with the API Level 7! Do you know a different way?

Comment: Right, it's first available in `3.1` which is `API Level 12`.  An `API Level 7` device shouldn't have a USB port.  Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the unique ID of an android connected USB device using UsbDevice.getDeviceId() method.

Please check the below links for more details.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html#getDeviceId()

More than Id, Please check other methods of class 'UsbDevice'.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html

Comment: It is not compatible with the API Level 7! Do you know a different way?

Comment: `getDeviceId()` returns an integer that is *not* persistent across USB  disconnects. that means if you unplug your USB device and plug it back in it will have a different device ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`UsbDevice.getVendorId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html#getVendorId()) and [`UsbDevice.getProductId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html#getProductId()) which is unique as long as the user doesn't connect the very same model of device twice, which should happen close to never.

Given that vendor ids are max. 4 hex digits you can left-shift the vendor ID by 16 bits and then add the product ID to get a model specific unique `int` identifier. Kotlin code:

```
val device: UsbDevice = ...
int modelId = (device.vendorId shl 16) + device.productId
```