# Programmatically obtaining the vendor ID, product ID of a USB device on Android platform

Tags: android, usb

I want to get Vendor ID and product ID of attached USB device via my Android Application.

Can anyone has idea how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the id (or some unique properties) of the USB devices connected to my Android device, programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488521/how-can-i-get-the-id-or-some-unique-properties-of-the-usb-devices-connected-to)

Comment: Where & how is what attached and what ids do you want to get? E.g the Android device that runs your app acts as USB Host (via [OTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go)?) and you want to get ids of an usb thumb drive plugged into the android device? Or in reverse and the Android device is client (like it is when you use USB debugging)?

Comment: yes device is attached via USB host

Answer (score 1):

[USB Enumeration](https://github.com/alt236/USB-Device-Info---Android)

This is a sample project you can refer.

Its implementation includes 2 kindes of USB enumeration.

1 ] By using **Android API**s.

2 ] By **cat** ing the communication files generated in the USB mounted path.

Comment: thax for reply.. will test and let u know

Comment: Feel free to ask any doubts regarding the mentioned project

Comment: hii @Don Chakkappan . when I am fetching usb devices its gettig all device inside Tablet while I want to get only those devices which are connected via USB port or OTG port.how can i apply filter

Answer (score 0):

UsbDevice class has a method to retrieve the product id and vender id.
You can refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html