# Getting the android ProductID and VendorID for my Android device

Tags: android

This question is not duplicate for [Programmatically obtaining the vendor ID, product ID of a USB device on Android platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525153/programmatically-obtaining-the-vendor-id-product-id-of-a-usb-device-on-android)

Because I am not trying to get the VendorID and ProductID for the attached device, I am trying to get the PID and VID for the Android phone to do something with them, how to get them. Unfortunately the class UsbDevice represents an attached UsbDevice which is not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the build fields, like

Manufacturer:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MANUFACTURER

etc, can one of these do what you want?

Comment: Thanks for help, Unfortunately none of then is PID or VID, I can know that when I connect the device to windows and open it's properties on the Device Manager,  on the device manager it explicitly says PID is x and VID is y, and none of the values here is the same, I have been here before but could not get anything out of this

Comment: That is weird, how come the android sdk does not give them directly out of the box?

Comment: Maybe a combination of these identifiers could be classes as Personally Identifiable Info (PII) and that's why they don't allow access. Is annoying when it can be gotten easily when the device is plugged in.  What is the scenario that you want the info in? Is the device plugged in at any time?

Comment: I want to send them to my desktop application to identify that this is a phone and nothing else like a camera for example

Comment: No problem. If you have a desktop application, can't that application query the USB devices, or use adb to talk to to your app to confirm that it is a phone that's plugged in?

Comment: We can't do it without relying on PID and VID both not one alone.